Blazor 7 migration to Blazor 8 InteractiveServer - error await Js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js");
We have a Blazor 7 Server application that has the following in our layout and it works:
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await Js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js");
            await Js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/bootstrap.min.js");
            await Js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js");
            await Js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js");
            await Js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/main.js");         
        }
    }
}

I am trying to migrate over to Blazor 8 InteractiveServer render mode, and the above fails.
The error we are getting is:

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
blazor.web.js:1 [2024-04-16T13:43:47.668Z]
Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:44373/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://localhost:44373/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
at ProviderPortal_Blazor8.Components.Layout.PreAuthLayout.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender) in C:\Source\Web Development\ProviderPortal\Branches(Feature)\GLO ProviderPortal_8\ProviderPortal_Blazor8\Components\Layout\PreAuthLayout.razor:line 30
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

Please help, I cannot solve this issue!
I have fiddled with rearranging the order of these "import" lines, I have also rearranged items in the App.Razor file:
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />    
    <base href="@BaseUrl" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ProviderPortal_Blazor8.styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://blazor.cdn.telerik.com/blazor/5.1.1/kendo-theme-default/all.css" />
    <script src="https://blazor.cdn.telerik.com/blazor/5.1.1/telerik-blazor.min.js" ></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon/favicon.ico">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" />
    <link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet" />      
    
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
</head> 

As well as rearranged some items in the program.cs file:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
using Blazored.SessionStorage;
using ProviderPortal_Blazor8.Authentication;
using ProviderPortal_Blazor8.Components;
using ProviderPortal_Blazor8.Models;
using ProviderPortal_Blazor8.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
//builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
//builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; }); // used to get debug information for javascript.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "CustomScheme";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "CustomScheme";
})
.AddScheme<CustomAuthOptions, CustomAuthenticationHandler>("CustomScheme", options => { });
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddTelerikBlazor();
//to get new blazor 8 authentication working hit this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77698959/blazor-net-8-own-authentication

builder.Services.AddScoped<ProtectedSessionStorage>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserApplicationState>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserAccountService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<WcfService>();
builder.Services.Configure<HubOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB or use null
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",
         optional: false,
         reloadOnChange: true)
     .AddJsonFile(string.Format("appsettings.{0}.json",
         Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")
             ?? "Production"),
         optional: true,
         reloadOnChange: true)
     .Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

//app.UseRouting();

app.Run();


1)could you try to check manually browsing the js file opening in the new tab with the full url eg"https://localhost:44373/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" 2)check content type of the js file. 3)make sure you js file is located in the wwwroot folder.
